# where is the real quasar ssr express server?

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am building a quasar and vue.js app and I want to add a MongoDB API with an express server, there that /ssr-src/ dir where there is an index.js file with basic express app routing:

```
/*
 * This file runs in a Node context (it's NOT transpiled by Babel), so use only
 * the ES6 features that are supported by your Node version. https://node.green/
 *
 * WARNING!
 * If you import anything from node_modules, then make sure that the package is specified
 * in package.json > dependencies and NOT in devDependencies
 *
 * Note: This file is used only for PRODUCTION. It is not picked up while in dev mode.
 *   If you are looking to add common DEV & PROD logic to the express app, then use
 *   "src-ssr/extension.js"
 */
console.log("got here!") // I added
const express = require("express"),
  compression = require("compression");

const ssr = require("quasar-ssr"),
  extension = require("./extension"),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const serve = (path, cache) =>
  express.static(ssr.resolveWWW(path), {
    maxAge: cache ? 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 : 0
  });

// gzip
app.use(compression({ threshold: 0 }));

// serve this with no cache, if built with PWA:
if (ssr.settings.pwa) {
  app.use("/service-worker.js", serve("service-worker.js"));
}

// serve "www" folder
app.use("/", serve(".", true));

// we extend the custom common dev & prod parts here
extension.extendApp({ app, ssr });

// this should be last get(), rendering with SSR
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
  // SECURITY HEADERS
  // read more about headers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers
  // the following headers help protect your site from common XSS attacks in browsers that respect headers
  // you will probably want to use .env variables to drop in appropriate URLs below,
  // and potentially look here for inspiration:
  // https://ponyfoo.com/articles/content-security-policy-in-express-apps

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
  // res.setHeader('X-frame-options', 'SAMEORIGIN') // one of DENY | SAMEORIGIN | ALLOW-FROM https://example.com

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection
  // res.setHeader('X-XSS-Protection', 1)

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options
  // res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') // one of '*', '<origin>' where origin is one SINGLE origin

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-DNS-Prefetch-Control
  // res.setHeader('X-DNS-Prefetch-Control', 'off') // may be slower, but stops some leaks

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy
  // res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', 'default-src https:')

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox
  // res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', 'sandbox') // this will lockdown your server!!!
  // here are a few that you might like to consider adding to your CSP
  // object-src, media-src, script-src, frame-src, unsafe-inline

  ssr.renderToString({ req, res }, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.url) {
        res.redirect(err.url);
      } else if (err.code === 404) {
        console.log(404,'!!')
        res.status(404).send("404 | Page Not Found foo bar"); // I added foo bar
      } else {
        // Render Error Page or Redirect
        res.status(500).send("500 | Internal Server Error");
        if (ssr.settings.debug) {
          console.error(`500 on ${req.url}`);
          console.error(err);
          console.error(err.stack);
        }
      }
    } else {
      res.send(html);
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at port ${port}`);
});
```

but none of my logs or changings are happening when I run $ queser dev -m ssr
also the `Server listening at port ${port}` is not showing.
need your help!

quasar version 1.0.7
debian 10

Answer (score 0):

```
src-ssr/index.js
```

From the comment notes, it seems like it is for Production only and will not visible in dev mode.
"Note: This file is used only for PRODUCTION"

You may want to use the src-ssr/extension.js instead.